# Prove that the shortest path between two points in a Euclidean space is a straight line.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've tried using the following distance formula: $$d(A,B)=\int_{A_{x}}^{B_{x}}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\, dx.$$ But couldnt do much with it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Answer (score 1):

$$d(A,B)=\int_{A}^{B}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\, dx \geq \int_{A}^{B}\sqrt{1+0}\, dx $$

Comment: Claude, that can't be so simple: the $A$ and $B$ in the integral are actually abscissas (that is, $x_A$ and $x_B$). In order to get from the *point* $A$ to the *point* $B$, the ordinate ($y$) must also change. Your answer is correct of $y_A=y_B$, and then the distance is indeed $|x_A-x_B|$. Otherwise $f'$ can't be identically zero: it must at least allow to increase (or decrease) the value of $y$ to get from $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

1) Original $X,Y$ system.

2) Translated system $X'Y':$

$O'$ at $A$, $X',Y'$ parallel to $X,Y$ ; $B'$ at $B$.

3) Rotated $X'',Y''$ system,

$O'$ at $O''$, $B''$ at $B$, where $B''$ lies on $X''$ axis.

4) In $X", Y''$ :

$f_2(0'')=0$; $f_2(b'')=0$.

5) Shortest distance

$I''= \int_{0''}^{b''}\sqrt{1+(f_2'(x''))^2)}dx''$ .

$(f_2)'(x'')= 0''$, i.e. $f_2(x'')= c=0''$, does the trick(Why?),

assuming rotation and translation do not change the length of a curve.